# PHP - MVC - Zend - Action files vs Class methods - performance?

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, class

I just wanted to ask if anybody knows some tests/results of the above?

It seems like one could perceive it as negligible, but since a PHP webserver is supposed to run under a high load... it could make a considerable difference.

It seems like its not that complicated to force Zend, to dispatch to action files...

"In most cases, however, you should simply extend the abstract class Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract, in which each of these have already been defined, or Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard to modify functionality of the standard dispatcher.

Possible reasons to subclass the dispatcher include a desire to use a different class or method naming schema in your action controllers, or a desire to use a different dispatching paradigm such as dispatching to action files under controller directories (instead of dispatching to class methods)."

kind regards,
and thanks in advance,
kriscom

Comment: Zend is somewhat heavy. Sure you will gain in performance removing what you don't need, but will loose in scalability. But, I still didn't get the point of compare Action Files vs Class methods. What are you trying to say? Action file and class methods, isn't both a class with methods (also know as actions)?

Comment: classes do imply imply both cpu and memory overhead... the question is how big/small is the difference...